# Trying to fix "Could not find a declaration file for module" from aws-appsync lib cause another error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using `aws-appsync` library and I'm getting this error:

> (4,42): Could not find a declaration file for module '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types'. 'node_modules/aws-appsync/node_modules/@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>     Try `npm install @types/redux-offline__redux-offline` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types';`

Then I added `declare module @redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types;` to my `typings.d.ts` to check if that error goes away but I got other:

> /node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/store.d.ts
>   (13,69): Cannot use namespace 'NetworkCallback' as a type.

Now I don't know how to fix the last error because I didn't find many pieces of information about it on the internet.

I don't know if this is important, but `packages/web/node_modules/@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types.js` is a file only with `"use strict";` line.

A solution that works is setting `noImplicitAny: false`, but I've read about it and it's not a good one.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like [awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js#280](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/280).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I open the file `/node_modules/aws-appsync/lib/store.d.ts` and there are two types imported from `@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types`:

```
import { NetInfo, NetworkCallback } from '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types';
```

Then in `typings.d.ts` I just added:

```
declare module '@redux-offline/redux-offline/lib/types' {
  export type NetInfo = any;
  export type NetworkCallback = any;
}
```

and the problem was gone.

Comment: wouldn't this fail on a fresh `npm install` ? you shouldn't be modifying the generated files because anyways they are going to be downloaded/generated again.. :/

Comment: The `typings.d.ts ` isn't in the `node_modules` but in the project files.

Comment: Aah! Also I saw that that github source of `@redux-offline/redux-offline` from version `v2.3.1` onwards now have `typings.d.ts` file containing all type declarations required. So you could also either configure `tsconfig.json` file to use this file for types or just copy paste it in your source code and refer it from there. It is still better than declaring types to `any` [refer github typings.d.ts](https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/blob/v2.3.1/typings.d.ts)